# How to initialize NumPy array with different default value for each column?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to initialize a NumPy matrix of size (x,y) where y is very large.

The first column of the matrix is an ID (integer), and the rest are triplets (int8), where each member of the triplet should have a different default value.

i.e. assuming the default values are `[2,5,9]` I'd like to initialize the following matrix:

```
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
...
```

The fastest way I could think of initializing the matrix is:

```
defaults = [2, 5, 9]
mat = numpy.zeros(shape=(x,y),
                  dtype=['i'] + ['int8'] * (y - 1))
# fill the triplets with default values
for i in range(1, y/3):
    j = i * 3
    mat[:, j]   = defaults[0]
    mat[:, j+1] = defaults[1]
    mat[:, j+2] = defaults[2]
```

What is the fastest way to initialize such a matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at [numpy.tile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.tile` with reshaping the value array,for example :

```
>>> b=np.array([2,5,9])
>>> b=b.reshape(3,1)
>>> np.tile(b,3)
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

Then you can use `np.dstack` to rotate the array then use `np.hstack` to add the zeros columns :

```
>>> np.hstack((np.zeros((3,1)),np.dstack(new)[0]))
array([[ 0.,  2.,  5.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  5.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  5.,  9.]])
```

Or you can repeat the none zero part again with `tile` :

```
>>> np.hstack((np.zeros((3,1)),np.tile(np.dstack(new)[0],4)))
array([[ 0.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  2.,  5.,  9.]])
```

**EDIT:**

Just for clarification, the simple one liner is this:

```
defaults = [2, 5, 9]
np.hstack((np.zeros((x,1)), np.tile(defaults, (x,y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution using just the `np.tile()` function:

```
# Create a footprint array
a = np.array([2, 5, 9])

# Use the footprint array to create the required final array
res = np.tile(a, (4, 3))

>>>res
array([[2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       [2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       [2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       [2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9]])
```

For a detailed use of `np.tile()` see the [official numpy page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it this like this,

```
np.tile([0] + [2, 5, 9] * 4, (3, 1))
```

Here I've used list addition and list multiplication to create the first row, then used `np.tile` to replicate that over three rows. `np.tile` automatically converts the list to an array before replicating it vertically three times.  You could wrap this into a function that looks something like this if you wanted to,

```
def make_array(triple, n_triple, n_row):
    return np.tile([0] + list(triple) * n_triple, (n_row, 1))
```

Here I've forced `triple` to be a list, but if you're careful to only pass a list to the `triple` variable when you call this function you wouldn't need that.

Good luck

Comment: I think you got confused- what you wrote as n_y is actually x in my example. You also did the replication in the y axis (the columns) by using list multiplication which I think is slower than NumPy's methods.

Comment: I fixed my solution to be more descriptive. IMO your use of `x, y` is confusing because `x, y` are often used for horizontal and vertical coordinates (e.g. in a plot). As far as speed goes, sure `np.tile` is faster for large values of `n_triple`, but most of the time it is inconsequential and I'd argue my code is significantly simpler and easier to read. If I'm scripting something quick and dirty I don't have to think about how the dimensions of `np.zeros`, `np.tile`, and `np.hstack` all work together.

Comment: you're right about the `x, y` notation, probably `m, n` would've been better. Regarding the list multiplication- it is indeed simpler, but for large y's it'll be a lot slower than the NumPy implementation. And in any case maybe using a generator expression would be better, like such- `(i for j in range(n_triple) for i in [2, 5, 9])`